# Data passed to handlebars template not showing in the client side

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js, sequelize.js, express-handlebars

I passed a viewData to the handlebar template like this

```
app.get('/employee/:value', (req, res) => {
    let viewData = {};
    dataService.getEmployeeByNum(req.params.value).then((data) => {
        if (data) {
            viewData.employee = data;
        } else {
            viewData.employee = null;
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        viewData.employee = null;
    }).then(dataService.getDepartments).then((data) => {
        viewData.departments = data;
        for (let i = 0; i < viewData.departments.length; i++) {
            if (viewData.departments[i].departmentId == viewData.employee.department) {
                viewData.departments[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        viewData.departments = [];
    }).then(() => {
        if (viewData.employee == null) {
            res.status(404).send("Employee not found");
        } else {
            res.render("employee", { layout: 'main', viewData: viewData })
        }
    })
});
```

and try to use it in the client side like this but ain't showing at all

```
<h2>{{viewData.employee.firstName}} {{ viewData.employee.lastName}} - Employee: {{ viewData.employee.employeeNum}}</h2>
```

I created an helper function to **stringify** the viewData object and this showed

```
{"employee":[{"employeeNum":3,"firstName":"Foster Lewa","lastName":"Billy","email":"louis.jessica86@gmail.com","SSN":"935-74-9918","addressStreet":"8 Midway Park","addressCity":"New York","addressState":"NY","addressPostal":"111","maritalStatus":null,"isManager":true,"employeeManagerNum":1,"status":"Full Time","department":3,"hireDate":"12/02/1999"}],"departments":[{"departmentId":1,"departmentName":null},{"departmentId":2,"departmentName":null},{"departmentId":3,"departmentName":"New Department"}]}
```

But never worked in the client side (html), what could be wrong ?

Comment: Employee is an array of objects not an object it'll not be access like the way you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<h2>{{viewData.employee.1.firstName}} {{ viewData.employee.1.lastName}} - Employee: {{ viewData.employee.1.employeeNum}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **viewData** was passed as an array to the template and here is what I did to get the values

```
<h2>{{viewData.employee.[0].firstName}} {{ viewData.employee.[0].lastName}} - Employee: {{ viewData.employee.[0].employeeNum}}</h2>
```

Thanks!